# What is the best practice to publish online the /doc folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails (4.1.5) and I have generated a full documentation which has been put in /doc as by default. My app is publish online but internally. I would like to expose this documentation through an URL part of my actual (e.g. http://myapp.com/doc). I want to find a way to automate this as the "generate the doc" action will be done on my side to refresh the documentation.

Somebody have any idea what should be the trick for this? Route (if so, how), should I create a controller for that specifically?

Thank you in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this using Dropbox. I run my documentation generator command and have it output to a location in my Dropbox folder. Then, my colleagues can simply open the index.html file at the shared location to view the documentation. But, in your case I suppose you could have your myapp.com/doc url redirect to the dropbox location? The advantage of all this being that you don't have to redeploy to have updated documentation -- just regenerate the docs since Dropbox does the uploading and hosting for you.